# Chrome won't change button text in loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey, firefox-addon-webextensions

In firefox all work fine. Using tampermonkey and webextensions (addons). Example of code:

```
while (pc == 10) {
  button3.textContent = "Scraping page " + page + "..."
  var url ="https://somelink.to/page?"+page
  xhr.open('GET', url, false);
  xhr.send();

  var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

  obj.push(json.posts)
  pc = json.posts.length

  if (page == plimit) {
    pc = "what you are doing here?"
  }
  page++  
}
```

Before used `.innerHtml`. Also used `setTimeout(button3.textContent = "Scraping page "+page+"...",300)` . Not work too. I don't know why in firefox work but not in chrome. Also when button clicked it look like freezed (pressed while script running). In Firefox it just clicked.

Comment: ```json.posts.length``` is it always 10?

Comment: This return current json posts count. Each page can contain 10 posts. I can't find page count thats why using this. Final page less than 10 posts. `plimit ` variable is for limit max page count (typed by user)